# Where can I find all the followers of a proposal on area51?

Tags: feature-request, support, area-51, followers

When viewing the definition phase of a proposal on Area 51, we get in the right sidebar list of up to 40 most recent followers.

Where can I find the full list? Can such list be added, if doesn't exist?

Comment: Turned this into feature request, just to be safe.

Comment: Can they be accessed in SEDE?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this information is not public, i.e. we can't get the full list of followers.

Otherwise, pretty sure [Is there a way to see all of the followers?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6558/is-there-a-way-to-see-all-of-the-followers) (posted on Area 51 meta site) would have gotten an answer by now.

Not sure if this is on purpose (privacy reasons) or not, but you can see if specific user is following a proposal in their profile page, [e.g.](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/133185/sean-mcmahon?tab=stats)

> [image: example for followed proposals of a user]

Comment: It's somewhat odd since you *can* see everyone committed to the proposal.

Comment: @Catija true, not sure what's the reasoning. Might be simple overlook.